# Database to Entity Naming Conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework, naming-conventions, reverse-engineering, ef-power-tools

Currently I am using EF 5.0.0 with EF Power Tools 3. I am trying to do reverse engineering from an existing database with reverse engineering code first (Power Tools 3). The sample of doing this can be found at this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620).

The only problem of doing this is the name of my database objects. My database objects using small words and underscore as space, E.g: item_cart. However I don't want that kind of naming standard to be passed to my C# application.

Then I tried to tweak the template to convert each table/field name to follow the application naming standards. This is the current conversion tool I have done till now.

```
    public static string SqlNameToEntityName(string name)
    {
        StringBuilder entityName = new StringBuilder();

        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return name;
        else if (!name.Contains('_'))
        {
            return name[0].ToString().ToUpper() + name.Substring(1);
        }

        string rippedName = name;

        while(rippedName[0] == '_')
        {
            rippedName = rippedName.Substring(1);
        }

        do{
            entityName.Append( CustomConvention.UpperFirstChar( rippedName.Substring(0, rippedName.IndexOf('_')) ) );
            rippedName = rippedName.Substring(rippedName.IndexOf('_')+1);
        }while(rippedName.Contains('_'));

        entityName.Append( CustomConvention.UpperFirstChar(rippedName) );

        return entityName.ToString();
    }

    public static string UpperFirstChar(string name)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)) return "";

        return name[0].ToString().ToUpper() + name.Substring(1, name.Length-1).ToLower();
    }
```

Then in Entity.tt, I have modified the template using this static method. `columnName = CustomConvention.SqlNameToEntityName(columnName);`. Using this approach, I can convert the table names from `item_cart` to `ItemCart` well enough (not tested yet though).

Lastly, here is my questions:

- Currently I cannot change the .cs file name to following the naming convention. So it still stay as item_cart.cs
- Will my approach make problems in the future?
- Is there any more better (standard/cleaner) way to doing this?
- Beside from this reverse engineering, what is the best (fastest and cleanest) way to map tables (maybe views and procedures) to entities?

Possible related question: [Resolving naming convention conflict between entities in EF4 and our database standards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680957/resolving-naming-convention-conflict-between-entities-in-ef4-and-our-database-st)

Comment: Have I stated my question clearly?

Comment: Can anyone answer this question please?